# How to pass just a single variable from a large js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

index.js

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var page = location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
    if (page != "minw.php") {goback = location.pathname;}
    var w1 = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var minw = 800;
    if (w1 < minw) {location.href = '../minw.php'};
});
```

On `minw.php` I have a button and clicking on it I want to go to `goback` address.

But `index.js` is a very large file and on `minw.php` I need just one single variable - `goback`.

Is there a way to get just this variable inside `minw.php` without linking entire `index.js` and without creating a new js file just for containing this variable ?

Maybe something like passing `$_SESSION` variable in `php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a GET variable:

```
if (w1 < minw) {location.href = '../minw.php?goBack=' + yourGoBackVarHere};
```

Then just read it from PHP:

```
$goBack = $_GET['goBack'];
```

If you don't want to mess the URLs with GET queries, using session will work, of course.

Comment: Can't believe that's so simple. Thanks a lot. I'll try.

Comment: Yup, no need to overcomplicate things, you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to store the variable in a sessoin , use ajax & send your varibale to a php file (minw.php or other ) & save the variable in a session ..

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'savesession.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        txt: 'goback',
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(data); // do with data e.g success message
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus.reponseText);
    }
});
```

in the php file

```
$_SESSION['goback'] = $_POST['txt'];
```